# cipher exceeds the 4X4 grid and prints out wrong cipher

Tags: python

So i have created this code below to make a 4*(the length of the cipher) grid based on the cipher text they have provided to work with any value up to 80 that is divisible by 4, i have added the validation so that it only allows characters less than 80 in length ad divisible by 4, so i wanted it to paste A K M R and below that individual characters lines by line, e.g.

```
   A    K    M    R
 ['D', 'C', 'B', 'A']
 ['B', 'F', 'D', 'C']
 ['D', 'F', 'B', 'F']
 ['D', 'D', 'D', 'F']
```

the cipher text that has been randomly generated is CFFDACFFDBDDBDBDCABBFCABDFFCBDFF (from a 16 character message input from the user converted into a cipher text)
but it gives out this output instead, so it outputs another 4 characters on the same line,
this problem does not occur when the input from the user is 8 characters and then is turned into a cipher text

```
      A    K    M    R
    ('C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'B')
    ('F', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'F', 'D')
    ('F', 'F', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'F', 'F')
    ('D', 'F', 'D', 'D', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'F')
```

it should actually be ..

```
      A    K    M    R
    ('C', 'A', 'D', 'B')
    ('C', 'F', 'D', 'B')
    ('F', 'C', 'B', 'D')
    ('A', 'C', 'F', 'D')
    ('F', 'F', 'D', 'B') 
    ('B', 'A', 'F', 'F')
    ('D', 'F', 'D', 'D')
    ('B', 'B', 'C', 'F')
```

source code...

```
 def decodecipher():

 global decode
 decode=input("Please enter your cipher text\n")
 grid1 = []
 finalcipher =""

 #AKMR
 print("  A    K    M    R")
 mygrid =([decode[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(decode),4)])
 grid2=list(zip(*mygrid))
 for i in range (len(grid2)):
    print(grid2[i])
```

I know it has something to do with my range , but I can't figure it out, i've turned using the length of my grid as a variable instead of defining the range as 4 but even that does not seem to  work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mygrid` has exactly the dimensions you want. You then call

```
grid2=list(zip(*mygrid))
```

which transforms `mygrid` (4x8) into `grid2` (8x4), and `print` the latter. Try

```
 for i in range (len(mygrid)):
     print(mygrid[i])
```

or, more pythonic:

```
for l in mygrid:
    print(l)
```

If you want each sub-list in `mygrid` to be a list of single characters, rather than a four-character string you can do this with a small modification to your list comprehension:

```
mygrid = [list(decode[i:i+4]) for i in range(0,len(decode),4)]
        # ^ add call to list
```

Comment: tried something just like this , just came up with 
  A    K    M    R , and no grid printing after that

Comment: Works absolutely fine here. The `zip` causes the problem you describe, I can't tell you why it won't `print` without seeing that code.

Comment: ah my mistake i did  for i in range (len(grid1)) instead of mygrid, its printing fine now :) now just have to get it in the right format thank you

Comment: This is why you should use the second version of the `print` loop; it's much less prone to error.

Comment: keep that in mind , still new to this haha ,thank you again :)

Comment: @johnrsharpe
Just one more problem thats occuring , I can't use this zip function is order to get the appropriate format that I require, is there something im doing wrong if i do this? 
     `print(" A K M R")` 
     `mygrid =([decode[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(decode),4)])` 
     `for i in mygrid:`
         `list(zip(*mygrid))`
     `print(i)` 
Don't really want to get rid of the 'zip' function

Comment: Why don't you want to remove `zip`? It isn't helping and it's trivial to put back in later! If you must keep it, use it to create `list2` but print out `mylist`, or hold it until *after* the `print` loop.

Comment: @johnsharpe i just thought zip was the easiest function to get the specified matrix format to make it looks neat compared to an append, is there any other way i could possibly do it without the zip ?

Comment: Easier/neater than *what* `append`? You have already built the list of lists of 4-char strings, in the format you need, in `mygrid =[decode[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(decode),4)]`. I have edited my answer with what I think you want.

Comment: i saw the changes you made, it made more sense thank you